# How to read authorization header in JAX-RS service

Tags: java, header, authorization, jax-rs

I am new to Authorization header, trying to create authorization(and authentication) using a JAX-RS service

My snippet at the javascript looks like this:

```
            sUrl = getURL() + "/com.cabRoutePlanner.Login/Login";  
            var oHeaders = {};
            oHeaders['Authorization'] = "Basic " + btoa(getUserName() + ":" + getPassword());

            var request = {
                headers : oHeaders,
                requestUri : sUrl,
                data: connectionData,
                method : "POST"
            };
            OData.request(request, onSuccessForRegister, onRegError);
```

Now, I want to read this authorization header at the JAX-RS service, i.e username and password back in my Java Rest service and check with my db. What I am confused with is, I don't know how to consume this authorization header. If somebody could just show me the declaration of the function in the REST service and just to access my username and passwrd, it'd be great.

I wrote the code somehow, with a little intuition and great help from Eclipse

```
@Path("/Log")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response log(HttpServletRequest req)throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject returnObject = new JSONObject();
    String authorization = req.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authorization != null && authorization.startsWith("Basic")) 
    {
        //byte[] message = authorization.substring("Basic".length()).trim().getBytes();
        String credentials = authorization.substring("Basic".length()).trim();
        byte[] decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(credentials);
        String decodedString = new String(decoded);
        String[] actualCredentials = decodedString.split(":");
        String ID = actualCredentials[0];
        String Password = actualCredentials[1];
        String Result = actualLog(ID, Password);
        if(Result.equals("ID Does not exist"))
        {
            returnObject.put("Result", "ID Does not exist");
            return Response.status(401).entity(returnObject).build();

        }
        else if(Result.equals("Password incorrect for given User"))
        {
            returnObject.put("Result", "Password incorrect for given User");
            return Response.status(401).entity(returnObject).build();
        }
        else
        {
            returnObject.put("Result", Result);
            return Response.status(200).entity(returnObject).build();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        returnObject.put("Result", "Authorization header wrong");
        return Response.status(401).entity(returnObject).build();
    }
}
```

Now, here is the current Exception I am getting and I'm not able to understand it:

```
 Oct 06, 2014 4:13:59 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
 SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, and Java type interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
 The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
 application/octet-stream ->
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
 */* ->
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
 com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
 com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
 com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
 com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
 com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
 com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
 com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

Comment: You should use `@Context HttpServletRequest request` to inject request in your method. But I'd strongly suggest you to use Java EE security, and let the container handle the authentication instead of writing it by yourself.

Comment: Your's solved the issue perfectly, thanks Gas :). But I am not allowed to mark it green, not sure why??!! 

Meanwhile, Java EE Security, I considered it, but I am not sure if I can use it, if there are many registrations into the application for whom I have to provide login credentials, roles. So, to develop such a scenario, it'd be impossible right? Since, every new user I add, I have to add the user credential and role in the web-server.xml? If there's no way to automate this, then it'll be a problem for me, hence the handler to communicate with the DB!

Comment: Pavanraotk, you couldn't accept it as it was comment. I've added it as answer, so you can accept it now ;). I'll write a few more things about Java EE security later on.

Comment: Pavanraotk regarding Java EE security - in similar cases you create roles and map these roles to groups, not particular users. Then when you create new user, it is enough to add him to specific groups (which act as roles), rather than need to modify constraints in xml. Most servers provides API which allows you to plugin your code to the authentication process or even sample implementations like file or db registry. That's why for authentication I'd suggest using server infrastructure, for authorization, if it is very complex you can create your logic in the code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use `@Context HttpServletRequest request` to inject request in your method, like this:

```
public Response log(@Context HttpServletRequest req) throws JSONException
```

Other useful objects that could be injected using `@Context` are (see JAX-RS spec for details):

- `Application`
- `UriInfo`, `HttpHeaders`
- `SecurityContext`,
- `Providers`, `Request`
- `ServletConfig`, `ServletContext`, `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`

So in your case you could use also `@Context HttpHeaders headers` and then

```
List<String> authHeaders = headers.getRequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
```